# LTSpice Measurement on Plot

Tags: spice, ltspice

I am modeling different circuits in LTSpice and I cannot for the life of me find ways to annotate the plots with measurements. How can I perform simple measurements such as measuring 3dB points, max and min, rise time ect and annotate this on the plot?

[image]

Comment: If you click the signal name in the plot (the green text), you can get cursors. However, a separate window opens up that displays the information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible in LTspice itself, but you can check the LTspice user group at:  http://groups.yahoo.com/group/LTspice/ for a definitive answer. The way I do it is to put the cursor in the plot pane and click it, then click on Tools>Copy Bitmap to Clipboard, then launch Paint, paste the bitmap, and annotate away...

Comment: There is a .measure command in ltspice, you can use it to measure the parameters you want.